# How to get a list of connected clients to the sails/socket?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I need to list all connected clients in sails/socket, any easy way to do it?

I don't know if the best way is to use database or just get a list of users connected to the sails/socket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When possible, it's best to use the built-in pubsub methods that Sails adds to models for you, [documented here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelMethods.md).  Failing that, you can access low-level socket methods in v0.9.8 via `sails.io`, so it would be:

`var sockets = sails.io.sockets.clients();`

to get an array of socket objects.

In v0.10 it will be:

`var sockets = sails.sockets.subscribers();`

to get an array of socket *IDs*, which you can use with the other `sails.sockets` methods to publish messages and do other magic.